# Isosceles triangle proof

Tags: geometry

> In a neutral geometry, given $\triangle{ABC}$ with $A-D-B,$ $\ A-E-C,$ $\angle{ABE}\cong \angle{ACD},$ $\angle{BDC}\cong \angle{BEC}$ and the line segment $\overline{BE}\cong \overline{CD}$, then $\triangle{ABC}$ is an isosceles.

$A-D-B$ means the point $D$ is between $A$ and $B$.

Since we are in a neutral geometry then our traigle satisfies the side angle side axiom.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\triangle ADC\cong\triangle AEB$ by ASA:

- A: $\angle ABE=\angle ACD$
- S: $BE=CD$
- A: $\angle ADC=\angle ADB-\angle BDC=\angle AEC-\angle BEC=\angle AEB$

So $AC\cong AB$ as corresponding sides.

Comment: How did you get that $\triangle ADC\cong\triangle AEB
$?

Comment: @Alex : I expanded that part of the argument.